# My Scrapy Code is executed but nothing happens

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a problem with my python code:

```
import scrapy
import datetime
import time

starttime = time.time()
while True:

 local = datetime.datetime.now()
 heure = local.strftime("%H")
 minutes = local.strftime("%M")

 minute = (int(heure) - 9) * 60 + int(minutes)

 class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
      name = 'quotes'
      start_urls = [
           'https://www.google.com/finance/quote/TSLA:NASDAQ?sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjn0orhqefxAhVS3IUKHbX9BKoQ3ecFMAB6BAgQEBo',
      ]

      def parse(self, response):
           for quote in response.css('div.AHmHk'):
                cours = quote.css('div.YMlKec.fxKbKc::text').get()


 time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0))
```

When I execute this, I've no error message but my json file isn't written like I would

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What json file? I see no code trying to print/write to files. You've defined a class, but is the class ever created and parse method executed? Note: you shouldn't define classes within loops

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to know two things:

1. Classes are a great idea. But you need to call a class to execute it. An example can be found in the official Python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#scopes-and-namespaces-example
2. To save data to a .json you have to write it. Have a look at the documentation as well: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: You do not need to call a Scrapy class - https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#how-to-run-our-spider

Answer (score 0):

If you [start back at the tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#our-first-spider), you can see that you actually need to *open and write to a file*

The code you've shown doesn't do anything with the `cours` variable, so that is why you see nothing

Plus, you should not use a while loop in your code; if you want to repeat the scraper, do that from your terminal

```
#!/bin/bash
while : 
do 
  scrapy crawl quotes
  sleep 5
done
```